# In React, Is it possible to get data from a local file that's not in /src?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like my React app to fetch data from a server, but that server's address might change from time to time.
i have a file named `address.json` with the next line:
`{ "server_address" : "http://some-address:3030" }`

Is it possible for my app to read the address from that file without the need to compile the project again?

ideally `address.json` would sit in `/build` and the app will change the address on it's next fetch try without any need to compile.

thanks in advance

Comment: how your app will change the address ? I meant, if is there some logic to let the application 'calculate' the new server address ...

Comment: Normal way to do this is to deploy that file to your server and request it at runtime with a network call (e.g. it is not "local").

Comment: Do you already use `address.json` in the app to find the address at all? If yes, it's as simple as just changing that file and also copying it into your static build folder (if you have one, which based off of "compile" I think you do.) If not, then you'd need to add that functionality and recompile.

Comment: @BinaryMan i'll run a script that changes it, or even change it manually. my real problem is with the compilation time


@Samathingamajig the problem is that the file can only sit in ```/src``` and therefor gets compiled and doesn't exist anymore in the ```build/static``` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste your file into the `public` folder and then you can access that file using

let fileurl = location.origin+'/'+ your-filename-here

in your case put your address.json file in the public folder and then you can access that file using `location.origin+'/address.json'` url.

`location.origin` will give you the name of host and port

You can use any files in public fonts,images,json etc.

Comment: but how do i get information from that file then?

Comment: Do you have any idea about Axios or fetch?

Comment: fetch won't work because it's a local file, is Axios different?

Comment: No, once you put a file in public and you are trying to access it using url then it's not a local file anymore bro

Comment: thanks bro! it worked with the code i posted below.

Comment: Clicked down-vote by accident even though this solution is working for me. @DilipTarkhala, if possible. Edit the post and I can up-vote instead since that was my intention.

Answer (score 0):

### Ok, I was able to make it work with the following code:

```
async fetchAddressFromFile() {
    const file = `${location.origin}/address.json`
    return fetch(file).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(json => {
        return json.address
    })
}

...

const address = await fetchAddressFromFile()
```